# How to tell if an incoming request is a webmethod request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

In ASP.NET when a request comes in, how can I tell (prior to the actual webmethod gets called), if a request is a webmethod request?

Something along these lines:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (IsWebMethod())
        {
            DoLogging();
        }
    }
```

What tests do I need to accurately determine when IsWebMethod() should be true?

Why:  We're exposing several webservices (.asmx) and I'm trying to implement a DRY technique for capturing information about these calls.

Comment: See if IsCallback() will do the trick for you

Comment: WebMethod requests in this context are never callbacks.  These are calls to .asmx files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a WebMethod call is just a regular GET or POST HTTP request, I don't think you can do anything to identify whether this is a WebMethod call or not besides inspecting the Request Url and determining if it matches one of the URLs for your WebMethods.

In other words, assuming you web service is called `default.asmx` and has a method `DoSomething` you could inspect the request to see if it matches

```
default.asmx/DoSomething
```

and then log it. I guess it's safe to assume that since your web methods will be exposed under `default.asmx`, you can just look for that string in the Request's URL.

Comment: This is where I was heading in my own investigations.  I'm leaning towards : HttpContext.Current.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension.ToLower().EndsWith("asmx") && !HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.ToLower().EndsWith("asmx")

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a collection of paths and inspect the request URL for matching paths, or if all your web methods are under a set of classes you can inspect the `HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler`'s type and compare that against a known set of types where your web methods reside.